# Python 3 and Tkinter: Displaying Questions and Varying Answer Sets by OOP in Survey Form

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

I am creating a survey form with questions and varying sets of possible answers using Python 3 and Tkinter.

The following lines of codes are not displaying my survey questions and their answer sets. Instead, they produce an error <**main**.QuestionSet object at 0x000000B3CB464400>:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

question = " "
def button_press(btn):
    global question
    question = btn
    questionStatement.set(question)

# Create Class for sets of questions and their possible answers
class QuestionSet:

    def __init__(self, questionSet):

        self.question = questionSet           
        # to display answer options with radio button
        def answer_options():
            for counter in range(len(question)-1):
                radioButton = RADIOBUTTON(text=question[counter])
                radioButton.grid(row=2, column=counter)
        answer_options()

# List of questions and their possible answers
q1 = QuestionSet(["Assessment 1", "Yes", "No"])
q2 = QuestionSet(["Assessment 2", "Yes", "No", "Maybe"])
q3 = QuestionSet(["Assessment 3", "Agree", "Disagree"])
q4 = QuestionSet(["Assessment 4", "Yes", "No"])

# Display Questions
questionStatement = StringVar()
questionStatement.set(q1)
questionField = Label(textvariable=questionStatement)
questionField.grid(columnspan=10, sticky="E")

# button to select questions to be answered
button1 = Button(text="1", command=lambda: button_press(q1))
button2 = Button(text="2", command=lambda: button_press(q2))
button3 = Button(text="3", command=lambda: button_press(q3))
button4 = Button(text="4", command=lambda: button_press(q4))

button1.grid(row=2, column=0)
button2.grid(row=2, column=1)
button3.grid(row=2, column=2)
button4.grid(row=2, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Inside your `range` you refer to `guestion`, but I think you meant to refer to `self.question`. When you call `questionStatement.set(q1)`, you are setting it to the instance reference for `q1`, when it is expecting a string. `RadioButton` is titled-camel-case, not capitalised, also it expects `root` as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the string representation of a class, you can override the `__str__` method of your class. It should return a string. In your case you could do:

```
class QuestionSet:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.question = questionSet

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question[0]
```